# How to remove value from ArrayList<String> when another checkbox is checked

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-checkbox

I have tried a couple of ways to remove the value from the array list once the checkbox is deselected but seems I still have not succeeded.

The code below contains a switch statement that will hold our cases for each box. Basically when the user selects one of the boxes it stores the value into the `ArrayList<String>` and then I store access it's value in another method using `messageTotalTip = selection.get(0);`

Thanks in advance!

```
    /* Create a View for our Check Boxes */
public void selectTip(View view){

    /*Boolean object will check if our checkbox is checked or not*/
    boolean checked =((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()){

        /*Case if 15% is clicked*/
        case  R.id.cb15Percent:
            if(checked){

                /*store our value into the ArrayList*/
                selection.add("15");

                /*To make sure we cant click any other box*/
                cb18Percent.setChecked(false);
                cb20Percent.setChecked(false);
                cbCustomTip.setChecked(false);

                /*Try and make sure that our value is erased if unchecked */
                if(cb18Percent.isChecked() || cb20Percent.isChecked()||cbCustomTip.isChecked()) {

                    selection.remove("15");
                }

            } else {
               selection.remove("15");
            }
            break;

        /*Case if 18% is clicked*/
        case R.id.cb18Percent:
            if(checked){
                /*store our value into the ArrayList*/
                selection.add("18");

                /*Make sure we cant click any other box*/
                cb15Percent.setChecked(false);
                cb20Percent.setChecked(false);
                cbCustomTip.setChecked(false);


                /*Try and make sure that our value is erased if unchecked */
                if(cb15Percent.isChecked() || cb20Percent.isChecked()||cbCustomTip.isChecked()) {

                    selection.remove("18");
                }


            } else {
                selection.remove("18");
            }
            break;

        /*Case if 20% is clicked*/
        case R.id.cb20Percent:
            if(checked) {
                /*store our value into the ArrayList*/
                selection.add("20");

                /*Make sure we cant click any other box*/
                cb15Percent.setChecked(false);
                cb18Percent.setChecked(false);
                cbCustomTip.setChecked(false);


                /*Try and make sure that our value is erased if unchecked */
                if(cb18Percent.isChecked() || cb15Percent.isChecked()||cbCustomTip.isChecked()) {
                    selection.remove("20");
                }

            } else {
                selection.remove("20");
            }
                break;

        /*Case if the custom box is checked*/  /************ Add dialogue box later once smaller bugs are fixed ************/
        case R.id.cbCustom:
            if(checked){
                selection.add("100");

                /*Make sure we cant click any other box*/
                cb15Percent.setChecked(false);
                cb18Percent.setChecked(false);
                cb20Percent.setChecked(false);

                /*Try and make sure that our value is erased if unchecked */
                if(cb18Percent.isChecked() || cb20Percent.isChecked()||cb15Percent.isChecked()) {

                    selection.remove("100");
                }
            }else {
                selection.remove("100");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Can only one of them ever be checked at any one time?
2.Must at least one of them be checked?

Comment: Yes, and yes! This is a simple tip calculator and since I want to calculate the tip I need to be able to have only one value so that I can calculate the tip.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead?

Comment: Why would you use an array for you selected value if there is only one value selected at a time? Also, your code doesn't seem right: you're setting every other checkbox to false before checking if they are checked.... And then you're removing the value you actually want to keep instead of removing the value of the previously checked checkbox...

Comment: @Robbie08 So the structure you're looking for is called a radial edit :).

Comment: @CorneliusJEhmke Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
A big thanks to all you guys. I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was using a different approach before I wrote this post that made me use an ArrayList. After seeing some of your guys comments I realized I didn't need the ArrayList anymore.

FIX: Pretty much just set a global variable called messageTotalTip and set the value of it depending on the case.

Thank you all!